# How to get value before onChange in Bootstrap Mutiselect?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I get the value after onChange function called by this

```
 $('.type_id').multiselect({
        buttonWidth: '100%',

        onChange: function(option, checked, select) {
            var opselected = $(option).val();
            alert(opselected);
        }
    });
```

I want selected value before onChange which comes from database.I am using multiselect on update form. I have a Cancel button. If I click on Cancel button after onChange then the selected value get back to old value.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get that value after the change event fires because the onChange event is not cancelable, for example with e.preventDefault().

But you could capture the value on mouseenter and store it in a data-element:

```
$('.type_id').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).data('value', $(this).val());
});
```

Then:

```
$('.type_id').multiselect({
    buttonWidth: '100%',
    onChange: function(option, checked, select) {
        var opselected = $(this).data('value');
        alert(opselected);
    }
});
```

Comment: .on('mouseenter',function(){}); is not working if I use .mutiselect({}). If I comment the .mutiselect({}) code then its working.